# Additional BuddyPress custom profile tabs

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

Is there a way to add additional custom tabs under the BuddyPress member profile page? I mean a custom tab next to Activity, Profile, Messages, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a plugin called [BuddyPress Custom Profile Menu](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/buddypress-custom-profile-menu/) that does what you want.